# Python timedelta return negative value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, timedelta

I am trying to find the number of days between column 1 = Admission date and Column 2 = surgery date. This is the code that I am using to get the number of days.

```
df['ADMISSION.DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ADMISSION.DATE'], errors = 'coerce')
df['1ST.SURGERY.DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['1ST.SURGERY.DATE'], errors = 'coerce')
df['TIME_DELTA'] = (df['1ST.SURGERY.DATE'] - df['ADMISSION.DATE'])
df['TIME_DELTA'] = df['TIME_DELTA']/np.timedelta64(1,'D')
df['TIME_DELTA']
```

I get the following output

[image]

Majority of the delta is positive and correct but for example 79480 has a delta of -234.

For 79480, Admission date is 31/08/2021 and Surgery date is 01/09/2021  08:45:00.
Still the answer is negative.

Any suggestions for the same are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share all of your data? Or at least the raw data for some additional columns where the negative values appear

Comment: Try adding `dayfirst=True` to `pd.to_datetime(...)`

Comment: @It_is_Chris, thank you, this worked and all my date delta are positive. I cannot seem to find why this worked though. Can you please explain the reason for it? Cheers!

Comment: @AayushKaushal It is hard to tell without seeing the data but my guess is that some dates were converted incorrectly by not specifying dayfirst. Here is an example: `pd.to_datetime(['01-12-2022', '22-12-2022'], errors='coerce')` Notice how `01-12-2022` gets converted incorrectly to `2022-01-12` YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @It_is_Chris thank you, I believe this is the issue. Thank you for explaining